# Parallelization of PyMC

Tags: python, parallel-processing, pymc, pymc3

Could someone give some general instructions on how one can parallelize the `PyMC MCMC` code.  I am trying to run `LASSO` regression following the example given [here](http://www.austinrochford.com/posts/2013-09-02-prior-distributions-for-bayesian-regression-using-pymc.html). I read somewhere that parallel sampling is done by default, but do I still need to use something like `Parallel Python` to get it to work?

Here is some reference code that I would like to be able to parallelize on my machine.

```
x1 = norm.rvs(0, 1, size=n)
x2 = -x1 + norm.rvs(0, 10**-3, size=n)
x3 = norm.rvs(0, 1, size=n)

X = np.column_stack([x1, x2, x3])
y = 10 * x1 + 10 * x2 + 0.1 * x3

beta1_lasso = pymc.Laplace('beta1', mu=0, tau=1.0 / b)
beta2_lasso = pymc.Laplace('beta2', mu=0, tau=1.0 / b)
beta3_lasso = pymc.Laplace('beta3', mu=0, tau=1.0 / b)

@pymc.deterministic
def y_hat_lasso(beta1=beta1_lasso, beta2=beta2_lasso, beta3=beta3_lasso, x1=x1, x2=x2, x3=x3):
    return beta1 * x1 + beta2 * x2 + beta3 * x3

Y_lasso = pymc.Normal('Y', mu=y_hat_lasso, tau=1.0, value=y, observed=True)

lasso_model = pymc.Model([Y_lasso, beta1_lasso, beta2_lasso, beta3_lasso])
lasso_MCMC = pymc.MCMC(lasso_model)
lasso_MCMC.sample(20000,5000,2)
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It looks like you are using PyMC2, and as far as I know, you must use some Python approach to parallel computation, like [IPython.parallel](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/dev/parallel/).  There are many ways to do this, but all the ones I know are a little bit complicated.  Here is [an example of one, which uses PyMC2, IPCluster, and Wakari](http://continuum.io/blog/bayesian-estimation-hoops).

In PyMC3, parallel sampling is implemented in the `psample` method, but your reference code will need to be updated to the PyMC3 format:

```
with pm.Model() as model:
    beta1 = pm.Laplace('beta1', mu=0, b=b)
    beta2 = pm.Laplace('beta2', mu=0, b=b)
    beta3 = pm.Laplace('beta3', mu=0, b=b)

    y_hat = beta1 * x1 + beta2 * x2 + beta3 * x3
    y_obs = pm.Normal('y_obs', mu=y_hat, tau=1.0, observed=y)

    trace = pm.psample(draws=20000, step=pm.Slice(), threads=3)
```

Answer (score 11):

PYMC3 has merged the **psample** into **sample**.

To run in parallel set the parameter `njobs > 1`.

The usage for the pymc.sample function is:

`sample(draws, step, start=None, trace=None, chain=0, njobs=1, tune=None,
           progressbar=True, model=None, random_seed=None)`

Note if you set `njobs=None`, it will default to Number of CPUs - 2.

I hope this helps.